# Py2app ImportError for user-created module

Tags: python, macos, py2app, setup.py

So I have a directory tree like this:

```
/
  setup.py
  src/
    ui.py
    load.py
    search.py
    parser.py
    img.py
    obj.py
    #..etc
  res/
    img.py
```

Setup.py looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os
import shutil
import sys
import subprocess
import copy

from distutils.core import setup

if "py2app" in sys.argv:
    ## Move the setup script to the src/ folder, then re-run it
    shutil.copy("setup.py", "src")
    newArgv = copy.copy(sys.argv)
    newArgv[newArgv.index("py2app")] = "rerun"
    os.chdir("src")
    subprocess.call(["python"] + newArgv)
elif "rerun" in sys.argv:
    import py2app
    sys.argv[sys.argv.index("rerun")] = "py2app"

    setup(
        options={
            "py2app": {
                "packages": "wx",
                "site_packages": True
            },
        },
        app=["ui.py"],
        package_dir={"": "."})

    ## Go back up a directory level and copy the build and dist folders up as well
    os.chdir('..')
    for fldr in ["build", "dist"]:
        if os.path.exists(fldr):
            shutil.rmtree(fldr)
        shutil.move(os.path.join("src", fldr), ".")

    ## Copy the necessary data directories to their relevant locations in the app file
    for fldr in ["xml", "templates", "data"]:
        print "Copying %s..." % fldr
        shutil.copytree(fldr, os.path.join("dist/ui.app/Contents/", fldr))
    os.remove(os.path.join("src", sys.argv[0]))
```

(The reason I do the weird subprocess.call forky thing is because of a requirement to have setup.py in the root of the tree, but all the source in src/)

When I run `python setup.py py2app`, it finishes completely, but when I open ui.app, it gives the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/smith/Code/digital-directory/dist/ui.app/Contents/Resources/__boot__.py", line 127, in <module>
    _run()
  File "/Users/smith/Code/digital-directory/dist/ui.app/Contents/Resources/__boot__.py", line 122, in _run
    exec(compile(source, path, 'exec'), globals(), globals())
  File "/Users/smith/Code/digital-directory/dist/ui.app/Contents/Resources/ui.py", line 14, in <module>
    import load
ImportError: No module named load
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't put your src in `src`.  Use a more-standard Python project layout, and don't fool around with the "subprocess.call forky thing."

For example, follow the guidelines at http://kennethreitz.com/repository-structure-and-python.html.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this "more standard Python project layout"?

Comment: @glittershark: Sure, I added a link.